# Trying to compile existing matlab code but getting mex error: not a normal file or does not exist

Tags: linux, matlab, computer-vision, mex

I'm trying to set up a vehicle detection system from the LSVM code here: https://github.com/rbgirshick/voc-dpm

I'm using Red Hat Linux  with Matlab 2011a.

I've unpacked the above system's files and opened Matlab. I select the whole directory where I unpacked the files, and all the subdirectories in it and right-click and do "Add to Path".

Then I right-click on compile.m in Matlab and then hit Run.

But I get the following error:

```
mex: fv_cache/fv_cache.cc not a normal file or does not exist.

Warning: Maybe you need to call fv_cache('unlock') first?
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to go about fixing this?

I tried calling `fv_cache('unlock')` in different places in the compile file, but to no avail. I'm not really experienced with Matlab and the whole mex thing.

Comment: Well, `fv_ache/fv_cache.cc` looks suspicious to me.  Shouldn't that be  `fv_cache/fv_cache.cc`?  Also, try making sure your working directory is where `compile.m` is located and then type `compile` at the command line instead of right-click-click.  (It might also be some issue with your particular compiler but seems more likely to just be a path issue).

Comment: Right, that was just a typo in my question - I've fixed it. I'm really new to Matlab... Didn't the "add to path" option make this my working directory? The directory structure starts in voc-releast5, and that's the top folder that I "Added to path", and that's where compile.m resides. I have tried entering "compile" on the command line of matlab but got the same error. The definition of the compile command is: `compile(opt, verb, mex_file)`. So I also tried `compile('on','on')` ... but that didn't work.

Comment: I've also added the absolute path of `fv_cache` using the `addpath()` command in the matlab command line. But I'm getting the same error. I also added this path using  File>Set Path. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The error you are getting is not related to a MATLAB search path, since the command itself (`compile`) is being found and run.  The mex source file that `compile` is looking for is treated more like a data file, and is referenced from the current working directory.  That's why @nkjt recommends that you set your working directory to the directory containing `compile.m` (the command to use is `cd`), rather than mess around with the MATLAB search path.

Comment: any luck please update?

Answer (score 0):

This may because the fv_cache.cc not compiled correctly. My solution is using $ mex -DMX_COMPAT_32 $ when compile on a 64-bit machine.